# Add node properties in html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, node-red

I want to add new properties to a custom node with jQuery. I use the jQuery code in "oneditprepare" and the jQuery function adds the properties in the Edit window. But if I click on Deploy and if I go to the Edit window again, the jQuery properties are gone.

I have added the properties with `$(...).append(...);`

Is there are possiblity to add properties with jQuery, while Node-Red is running. I push the data from the html to the js code with an array and it works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `oneditsave` function to ensure the new parameters are stored properly.

Look at the switch node or the change node for examples of using the *EditableList* type as this is probably the best way to approach this.